# ASP.NET web API response shows escape characters in browser and Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, escaping

I'm learning how to create web API's with ASP.NET, but I'm having issues with getting my JSON response to look nice in the browser.

When printing the JSON string to the debug console, it looks fine:

```
{
  "a": 2,
  "b": "hello"
}
```

But when looking at it in the browser or through Postman (even in "Pretty view"), I get this:

```
"{\r\n  \"a\": 2,\r\n  \"b\": \"hello\"\r\n}"
```

Can I get the browser to display the result nicely?

Here is my test model:

```
namespace Test.REST.Models
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int a;
        public string b;

        public Test(int a, string b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my test controller:

```
namespace Test.REST.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            Test.REST.Models.Test test = new Test.REST.Models.Test(2, "hello");
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);
            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it without specifying indented formatting? i.e. remove "Formatting.Indented"...as this is surely what is inserting the \r and \n's into the string.

Comment: @StephenByrne yeah, without that formatting, I get "{\"a\":2,\"b\":\"hello\"}" in the browser, so it still inserts some escape characters that I would rather that it didn't display. If I print this JSON response in VS before returning it, it looks fine: {"a":2,"b":"hello"}.

Comment: the only other thing i can think of is if the content-type header is not being set (i.e. set as "application/json") on your response so that the browser is interpreting this as a string literal. Perhaps as a test you could try changing Get to return an IActionResult, and then in the method return OK(json) and see if that's any better. If so you can then revert and manually set that header if you like.

Answer (score 1):

you have a bug,  fix class

```
public class Test
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }

    public Test(int a, string b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

After fixing I tested your code using VS 2019 and Postman.  Everything looks properly.

if I use

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

output

```
{
  "a": 2,
  "b": "hello"
}
```

and the same look  if I use a Chrome browser

after removing Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

output

```
{"a":2,"b":"hello"}
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, I am not sure why it works for you. I copied in your version of the Test class, but I still see the newline characters \r\n and escape characters in the browser and in Postman (the formatting still looks fine while printing the string in Visual Studio before returning it though). Could it be a thing with my project setup, or is there some way to tell the browser to decode \r\n properly?

Answer (score 0):

Use StringContent class

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test()
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
    var Response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    Response.Content = new StringContent(json , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return ResponseMessage(Response);
}
```

or even simpler

```
return Json(yourObject); //don't serialize your object
```