# How to solve .Net Framework MVC EntityFramework Self Reference Loop Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, json.net, .net-framework-version

I have book class that includes authors and also my author class includes books. So when I try to convert book to json string, it gives the referance loop error. So I do that

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllForOfficer()
    {
        Library library = _libraryManager.GetById(ProviderAuthorization.libraryId);
        List<Book> books = _bookManager.GetAll().Where(x=>x.Libraries.Contains(library)).ToList();
        
        return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(books, Formatting.Indented,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                    }));
    }
```

And this returns output like that

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Authors\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"Books\": [],\r\n        \"Id\": 4,\r\n        \"Name\": \"Texe Marrs\"\r\n      }\r\n    ],\r\n    \"Categories\": [],\r\n    \"Comments\": [],\r\n    \"Libraries\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"Books\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"Authors\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"Books\": [\r\n                  {\r\n                    \"Authors\": [],\r\n                    \"Categories\": [\r\n                      {\r\n                        \"Books\": [],\r\n                        \"Id\": 5,\r\n                        \"Name\": \"dede\",\r\n                        \"ClickCounter\": 0\r\n                      },\r\n                      {\r\n                        \"Books\": [],\r\n                        \"Id\": 6,\r\n                        \"Name\": \"asas\",\r\n                        \"ClickCounter\": 0\r\n                      }\r\n                    ],\r\n                    \"Comments\": [\r\n                      {\r\n                        \"User\": {\r\n                          \"Comments\": [],\r\n
```

I have book class like this

```
public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string ISBN10 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(13)]
    public string ISBN13 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }

    public int? NumberOfPages { get; set; }

    public int? Revision { get; set; }

    public int? LatestRevision { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public int ClickCounter { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserBook> UserBooks { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Library> Libraries { get; set; }
```

My output looks a little bit weird. It should be like "Authors":["Name":"Pete Mark"]. But there are some backslashes. I think I have a problem with converting class to json. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Why do you need convert to json string?  Can you post the whole action and what the action for?

Comment: You say it looks a little bit weird but do you get any errors?!?  From what I can see, your output looks normal.  The slashes are because you're viewing it as a string and it's encoded.  Throw the string into notepad, find \" and replace with " and then load the result into https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer ... if it works, you know the JSON is correct.

Comment: @Serge I updated action part. You can check it again. I want to create api and just want to send data as json.

Comment: @Skin I have no errors but when I do Formatting.Intended, It looks more weird. I just want to fix it. (I updated output and codes.)

Comment: @FurkanErol When you say "And this returns output like that", do you mean the output of the Console.WriteLine() when you log that on the server side? Because if it's the case, it's totally normal.

Comment: I think @Skin is correct. Alternatively if you use Visual Studio you can save the result of the serialization into a variable and while debugging, you can hover over the variable and view the current value with the json formatter. So you do not need that extra step with notepad and find and replace the backslashes.

Comment: @Serge .NetFramework 4.7.2

Comment: @MarvinS, true ...!

Comment: @wiwi I am testing it with postman, so it is postman's request output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody who says I dont actually need any conversion. I solved that problem using data transfer object. I created same classes. And convert it to dto by not equalizing child class's relationship objects (which is typed ICollection).

Here is my book entity.

```
public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string ISBN10 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(13)]
    public string ISBN13 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Publisher { get; set; }

    public int? NumberOfPages { get; set; }

    public int? Revision { get; set; }

    public int? LatestRevision { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public int ClickCounter { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserBook> UserBooks { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Library> Libraries { get; set; }
```

And here is BookDto class.

```
public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ISBN10 { get; set; }

    public string ISBN13 { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Publisher { get; set; }

    public int? NumberOfPages { get; set; }

    public int? Revision { get; set; }

    public int? LatestRevision { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public int ClickCounter { get; set; }

    public  List<CommentDto> Comments { get; set; }

    public  List<UserBookDto> UserBooks { get; set; }

    public  List<AuthorDto> Authors { get; set; }

    public  List<CategoryDto> Categories { get; set; }

    public  List<LibraryDto> Libraries { get; set; }
```

And I have my action here.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllForOfficer()
    {
        Library library = _libraryManager.GetById(ProviderAuthorization.libraryId);
        List<BookDto> booksDto = _bookManager.GetAll().Where(x => x.Libraries.Contains(library)).ToList().ConvertAll<BookDto>(x => new BookDto()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            ISBN10 = x.ISBN10,
            ISBN13 = x.ISBN13,
            Authors = x.Authors.ToList().ConvertAll<AuthorDto>(y => new AuthorDto() { Id = y.Id, Name = y.Name }),
            Categories = x.Categories.ToList().ConvertAll<CategoryDto>(y => new CategoryDto() { Id = y.Id, Name = y.Name, ClickCounter = y.ClickCounter }),
            Comments = x.Comments.ToList().ConvertAll<CommentDto>(y => new CommentDto() { Id = y.Id, BookId = y.BookId, CommentString = y.Comment1, Date = y.Date, Status = y.Status, UserId = y.UserId }),
            Libraries = x.Libraries.ToList().ConvertAll<LibraryDto>(y => new LibraryDto() { Id = y.Id, Address = y.Address, Location = y.Location, Name = y.Name, Status = y.Status }),
            UserBooks = x.UserBooks.ToList().ConvertAll<UserBookDto>(y => new UserBookDto() { Id = y.Id, Status = y.Status, BookId = y.BookId, BorrowDate = y.BorrowDate, LibraryId = y.LibraryId, UserId = y.UserId, ReturnDate = y.ReturnDate }),
            ClickCounter = x.ClickCounter,
            CreateDate = x.CreateDate,
            Description = x.Description,
            Image = x.Image,
            Language = x.Language,
            LatestRevision = x.LatestRevision,
            NumberOfPages = x.NumberOfPages,
            Publisher = x.Publisher,
            Revision = x.Revision,
        });
        return Ok(booksDto);
    }
```

Now I have Postman output is like that.

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "ISBN10": "123123",
    "ISBN13": "213123",
    "Name": "asdasd",
    "Publisher": "asdasd",
    "NumberOfPages": 2,
    "Revision": 2,
    "LatestRevision": 2,
    "Language": "asd",
    "CreateDate": "1010-10-10T00:00:00",
    "Description": "asdasd",
    "Image": null,
    "ClickCounter": 0,
    "Comments": [
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "UserId": 1,
            "BookId": 1,
            "CommentString": "TestComment",
            "Date": "2020-10-10T00:00:00",
            "Status": 1,
            "Book": null,
            "User": null
        }
    ],
    "UserBooks": [
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "UserId": 1,
            "BookId": 1,
            "LibraryId": 1,
            "BorrowDate": "1010-10-10T00:00:00",
            "ReturnDate": null,
            "Status": 1,
            "Book": null,
            "Library": null,
            "User": null
        }
    ],
    "Authors": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "TestAuthor1",
            "Books": null
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "TestAuthor2",
            "Books": null
        }
    ],
    "Categories": [
        {
            "Id": 5,
            "Name": "TestCategory0",
            "ClickCounter": 0,
            "Books": null
        },
        {
            "Id": 6,
            "Name": "TestCategory1",
            "ClickCounter": 0,
            "Books": null
        }
    ],
    "Libraries": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "asdasd",
            "Address": "asdasd",
            "Location": "asdasd",
            "Status": 1,
            "Officers": null,
            "UserBooks": null,
            "Books": null,
            "Users": null
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "asdasd",
            "Address": "asdasd",
            "Location": "asdasd",
            "Status": 2,
            "Officers": null,
            "UserBooks": null,
            "Books": null,
            "Users": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Also the problem could be resolved without using dto classes. Like that

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllForOfficer()
    {
        Library library = _libraryManager.GetById(ProviderAuthorization.libraryId);
        List<BookDto> booksDto = _bookManager.GetAll().Where(x => x.Libraries.Contains(library)).ToList().ConvertAll<BookDto>(x => new Book()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            ISBN10 = x.ISBN10,
            ISBN13 = x.ISBN13,
            Authors = x.Authors.ToList().ConvertAll<Author>(y => new Author() { Id = y.Id, Name = y.Name }),
            Categories = x.Categories.ToList().ConvertAll<Category>(y => new Category() { Id = y.Id, Name = y.Name, ClickCounter = y.ClickCounter }),
            Comments = x.Comments.ToList().ConvertAll<Comment>(y => new Comment() { Id = y.Id, BookId = y.BookId, Comment1 = y.Comment1, Date = y.Date, Status = y.Status, UserId = y.UserId }),
            Libraries = x.Libraries.ToList().ConvertAll<Library>(y => new Library() { Id = y.Id, Address = y.Address, Location = y.Location, Name = y.Name, Status = y.Status }),
            UserBooks = x.UserBooks.ToList().ConvertAll<UserBook>(y => new UserBook() { Id = y.Id, Status = y.Status, BookId = y.BookId, BorrowDate = y.BorrowDate, LibraryId = y.LibraryId, UserId = y.UserId, ReturnDate = y.ReturnDate }),
            ClickCounter = x.ClickCounter,
            CreateDate = x.CreateDate,
            Description = x.Description,
            Image = x.Image,
            Language = x.Language,
            LatestRevision = x.LatestRevision,
            NumberOfPages = x.NumberOfPages,
            Publisher = x.Publisher,
            Revision = x.Revision,
        });
        return Ok(booksDto);
    }
```

But there is a problem while converting ICollection objects. I convert ICollection to list to use ConvertAll method. But in the end I have to change it to ICollection. So this last code sample is not working. Maybe there is a way but I didnt search about it.

Answer (score 0):

you don' t need any special conversion, net will do it for you. If you try to make json looking prety, it doesn' t make any sense on the server side. You will have to deserialiaze or parse it on the client side after this.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllForOfficer()
{
        Library library = _libraryManager.GetById(ProviderAuthorization.libraryId);
        List<Book> books = _bookManager.GetAll().Where(x=>x.Libraries.Contains(library)).ToList();
        
        return Ok(books);
}
```

Comment: When I do like it, I get self reference loop error.  And also I want it to be json.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080635/asp-net-web-api-response-shows-escape-characters-in-browser-and-postman Here is what I want, but I could not do that.

Comment: @FurkanErol  Sorry, but what are you talking about? You have self reference loop when you return list of books?  All actions return data as json if you like it or not. You should forget about json when you use c#. Json is only good for javascript. I never used json explicitly for 20 years of net experience.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to solve your problem would be to add the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to your Authors, Categories and Libraries properties in the `Book` class (and potentially some other attributes in your other classes aswell).

A better way would be to write custom JsonConverters for those properties. For example, the `Book` class could use a `AuthorNameConverter` which converts an `Author` object into a `string` with the author's name when serializing. You can add that converter as an attribute of your `Authors` property, or add it in the available converters of your JsonSerializerSettings.

You can find an example of a JsonConverter here : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

For adding it as an attribute :

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(AuthorNameConverter))]
public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
```